# My Property is not rendring on the jsp in struts 2.0

Tags: struts2

I have set a property in Action class as follows

```
public class HelloWorld{
  public String execute() { ANNOTATION #1
  setCustomGreeting( GREETING + getName() );
  return "SUCCESS"; 
  }
  private String customGreeting;
  public String getCustomGreeting()
  {
    return customGreeting;
  }
  public void setCustomGreeting( String customGreeting ){
  this.customGreeting = customGreeting;
}
}
```

And i m trying to render it on jsp as follows

```
<%@ page contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="s" uri="/struts-tags" %>
<html>
<head>
<title>HelloWorld</title>
</head>
<body>
<h3>Custom Greeting Page</h3>
<h4><s:property value="customGreeting"/></h4> 
</body>
</html>
```

But it's printing nothing on the jsp, please help me?

Comment: Are you opening JSP page or action in address url?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Debugging suggestions:

- Put breakpoints (or trace statements, or whatever) in the methods to confirm whether or not they are called.
- Place an <s:debug/> tag on the page.
- If that doesn't give any hints, then enable more detailed logging (how to do this will depend on what logging framework is being used), specifically for OGNL.

Answer (score 0):

Your Code looks fine?

Do you call the JSP directly?

Is your Action mapped in the struts.xml?

Comment: yes my action is mapped in struts.xml, other contents on the target jsp are being displayed properly, but the problem is only with 
<h4><s:property value="customGreeting"/></h4>